# redirect_to doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I use `devise` and tried to do the next thing:

when the user sign in/up, I want to redirect him by his role_id (I let id of 1 for some users and 2 for the others).

if his role_id is 1, redirect him to `tasksadmins_path`, otherwise to `workers_path`.

so I tried something like:

`routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'user_sessions'} do
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
   root to: "workers#index"
end

resources :tasksadmins

resources :workers

root to: "workers#index"
```

and this is my `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include ApplicationHelper

    protect_from_forgery
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
        if current_user.role_ids == [2]
           redirect_to root_url
        else
           redirect_to tasksadmins_path
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `after_sign_in_path_for` doesn't work, so I added to 'create' the next lines:

**in the beginning, I wrote:**

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name)
```

**and then I wrote in the end of the 'create' function:**

```
sign_in(resource_name, resource)

if current_user.role_ids == [2]
   respond_with resource, :location => workers_path
else
   respond_with resource, :location => tasksadmins_path
end
```

**so my create looks so:**

```
class UserSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    include ApplicationHelper

    def create

        resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name)

        require "uri"
        require "net/http"

        ## get the user id from the database
        user_id = session['warden.user.user.key'][1][0];

        ## get the row by id
        user = User.find(user_id)

        # ============================
        # Ensure that a user exists
        # ============================

        code, body = http_request(Net::HTTP::Put.new("/api/v1/users/external/#{user_id}"), email: user.email);
        if code != 200
           Rails.logger.error("Unable to register user #{current_user.email} at Licensario");
        end

        sign_in(resource_name, resource)

        if current_user.role_ids == [2]
           respond_with resource, :location => workers_path
       else
           respond_with resource, :location => tasksadmins_path
       end

    end
end
```

Comment: See previous comment. Using standard method from Devise is much more better solution than hook into session controller.

Answer (score 1):

Devise has special method for this situation. You can overwrite after_sign_in_path_for. In ApplicationController

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
  town_path
 else
  users_path
 end
end
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested me and I got: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Comment: I don't know why I have too many redirects..
I wrote:   def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
     if current_user.role_ids == [2]
       redirect_to root_url
     else
       redirect_to tasksadmins_path
     end
  end

Comment: You should NOT redirect to this path. You should only give devise url to redirect. Devise try to redirect your redirect. Simple return url from after_sign_in_path_for method. 
def after_sign_in_path_for(user) 
  if current_user.role_ids == [2] 
    root_url
  else
    tasksadmins_path
  end
end